# Porque me sale textcontent of undefined pero a la vez puedo ver los resultados en la consola?

Tags: javascript, dom

Tengo dos arrays, uno con nombres de tokens y el otro son spans vacíos que necesito que tomen el nombre de esos tokens. Pero cuando ejecuto, me salta *Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined* pero me imprime el contenido de las etiquetaas con clase tokenname en consola.

```
const tokenNames = document.querySelectorAll('.tokenName');
const spanTokenNames = document.querySelectorAll('.spanTokenName');

for(let i=0; i<=tokenNames.length;i++){
    console.log(tokenNames[i].textContent);

    // spanTokenNames[i].innerText = tokenNames[i].textContent;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

creo que tenias que cambia "<=" por "<" :

```
i<=tokenNames.length;i++){
```

por :

```
i<tokenNames.length;i++){
```